# ComponentScan excludeFilters Not Working In Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a class which I want to exclude while component scanning. I am using the below code to do that but that doesn't seem to work although everything seems to be right

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "common", "adapter", "admin"}, excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ServiceImpl.class) })
```

Actually I want have "ServiceImpl" class, which implements "Service" interface, is being used in my rest api logic and while doing the integration test of an api I want to exclude this implmentation and load the mocked implementation. But this doesn't seem to happen as even after using the above I am getting the below error

```
No qualifying bean of type [admin.Service] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: ServiceMockImpl,ServiceImpl
```

I spent too much of time on this but nothing works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

After lot of work and research I noticed that Spring's behavior is little weird in term of component scanning.

Artifacts were like this :

`ServiceImpl` is the real implementation class which implements `Service` interface.
`ServiceMockImpl` is the mocked implantation class which implements `Service` interface.

I wanted to tweak the component scanning so that it only loads the `ServiceMockImpl` but not `ServiceImpl`.

I had to add the `@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ServiceImpl.class)`,  in the `@ComponentScan` of test configuration class, to exclude that particular class from component scanning. But both the classes were getting loaded even after doing the above changes and tests were failing.

After lot of work and research I found that the `ServiceImpl` was getting loaded because of the other class which was getting loaded and has `@ComponentScan` for all packages on top of in it. So I added the code to exclude the `Application` class from the component scanning as follows `@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = Application.class)`.

After that it worked as expected.

Code like below

```
@ComponentScan(
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = OAuthCacheServiceImpl.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = Application.class)
    },
    basePackages = {
        "common", "adapter", "admin"
    }
)
```

I have seen that lot of questions on component scanning are unanswered for long hence I thought to add these details as it may help somebody in the future.

HTH...

Comment: Great idea! This is what works for me as well:   
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.package", excludeFilters = @Filter(classes = {Controller.class, Configuration.class}) )`   
Looks like we have to explicitly tell Spring to skip Configuration classes.

Comment: Lifesaver... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At first,Thanks very much about the answers of  @Yuriy and @ripudam,but what makes me confused is when my excludeFilters contains Configuration.class I have to use @Import to import the Classe which  annotated by @Configuration.I found when i use excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,value{EnableWebMvc.class,Controller.class}),all works well.The ContextLoaderListener doesn`t regist the Controller at first.

For example

```
//@Import(value = { SecurityConfig.class, MethodSecurityConfig.class, RedisCacheConfig.class, QuartzConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "cn.myself" }, excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,value={EnableWebMvc.class,Controller.class}) })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue when using **@Configuration**, **@EnableAutoConfiguration** and **@ComponentScan** when trying to exclude specific configuration classes, but it didn't work!

Eventually I solved the problem by using [**@SpringBootApplication**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html), which according to Spring documentation does the same functionality as the three above in one annotation.

Another Tip is to try first without refining your package scan (without the basePackages filter).

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {Foo.class})
public class MySpringConfiguration {}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Exclude only excluided AutoConfiguration. Not beans and regualr Configuration

Comment: I will not definitely work. That exclude option is for only AutoConfiguration classes