# Spring Mvc Injection Error(Injection of autowired dependencies failed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm really new  in Spring MVC. I write a demo(use annotation),but it doesn't work.
[here is the construction of my demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5gTN.png)

```
public class WebInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { RootConfigure.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { Configure.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

in Configure.java,I declare the 'ContackDAO' bean ,like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "base")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Configure extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new   InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/resources/");
}

@Bean
public ContactDAO getContactDAO() {
    return new ContactDAOImpl();
}
}
```

in MainControl.java .I need to use ContackDAO,so I write this:

```
@Controller
public class MainControl {
@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String listContact() throws IOException{
    System.out.println(contactDAO.getBean());// getBean() returns "hello"
    return "hello";
}
}
```

when I run this demo, I get errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainControl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private base.dao.ContactDAO base.contorl.MainControl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [base.dao.ContactDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

what's wrong in my demo? Can you help me?

I find if I put the code:

```
@Bean
public ContactDAO getContactDAO() {
    return new ContactDAOImpl();
}
```

into RootConfigure.class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "base" }, excludeFilters = { @Filter(type =     FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class) })
public class RootConfigure {
@Bean
public ContactDAO getContactDAO() {
    return new ContactDAOImpl();
}
}
```

,the demo run successfully.I don't know why...

Comment: How many config classes do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not missing setter for contactDAO.

Comment: It is required for @Autowire to work. For more [info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm)

Comment: He's not using setter autowiring, he's defining bean using `@Bean` annotation. This type of autowiring is fine.

Comment: You don't need a setter when you are mentioning @Autowire on the element it self.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, a good practice is to follow the proper package structure.

```
i.e. in Your case you can put the configuration like this:

        base.dao.config 
        base.dao.impl

        base.mvc.config
        base.mvc.impl
```

And then include all these in top most configuration. This way it would be a clear separation about configuration for each type of beans that is 
    again for `@Repository`, `@Service` and `@Controller`

To Answer your question about why. because you are excluding your mvc configuration class in the RootConfig.java using excludeFilters.

check the link for `excludeFilters` in the RootConfig.java

You need to understand first what @EnableWebMvc does and what the excludeFilters does which is explained in below link

[ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

Some SO questions related to similar thing:

[excludeFilters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550494/componentscan-excludefilters-not-working-in-spring-4-0-6-release)

And one more: 
[Filter Specific Packages in Component Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238089/filter-specific-packages-in-componentscan)