# ComponentScan excludeFilters Not Working In Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are migrating Spring Boot 2 application to Spring boot 3.
We have a Configuration class MAppConfig in the package
com.xxxxx.xxx.manager;

In the spring boot application main class ManagerSpringBootApplication i have following code :

```
@EnableJms
@EnableCaching
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxxxx", excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MAppConfig.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = MBaseConfig.class)
})
@SpringBootApplication
@Push(value = PushMode.MANUAL,transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET)
@Theme(value = "manager-app")
public class ManagerSpringBootApplication implements AppShellConfigurator {
   SpringApplication.run(ManagerSpringBootApplication.class, args);
}
```

Exclude filter was able to filter out all the excluded class in Spring Boot 2 but failing in Spring boot 3

Tried the approaches as mentioned in the below stackoverflow link :
[ComponentScan excludeFilters Not Working In Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550494/componentscan-excludefilters-not-working-in-spring-4-0-6-release)

Tried Custom filter also.

But none of them worked.